# mvc form submits as get instead of post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Clients report the search function in my mvc application is returning no results on first attemps yet gives results on a second search with the same searchstring.

After some digging I found that if you leave a page open for a few minutes (2-5min) the search function would submit a GET request instead of a POST request, resulting in a searchstring with value NULL.

After extended searching I have yet to find an answer to this. The search function works and posts when actively working with the application, but leaving a page idle for a while and it no longer posts which is greatly annoying my clients.

here's the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form-custom", style = "width:350px;" }))
                        {
                                <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" style="height: 43px; width: 300px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; height: 40px; margin-top:5px; border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;" placeholder="Search student" required>
                        }
```

and the action:

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
    {
        return View(_repo.SearchStudent(search));
    }
```

I've added [HttpPost] to the action, which just results in a 404 error when the GET triggers.

For now I've 'solved' the issue by switching the form to FormMethod.Get, which seems to work, though the addition of a query string isn't ideal.

I'm still looking for a proper solution as I suspect other forms on the application of showing similar behavior (bug reports of changes going unsaved without errors, other actions throwing null exceptions when they really shouldn't, etc)

I've made similar projects before and never encountered this behavior. Could this be an IIS issue or settings related?

Edit: Found the culprit. Apparently the user's session times out. which results in a redirect to '\Account\Login?ReturnUrl="Student/Search"'. Since the application uses a SSO session the user gets logged back in immediatly and never notices. the return URL is then accessed as a GET request which explains the sudden switch from POST to GET. Switching the form to GET fixed the issue as the searchterm gets passed as a querystring and therefor doesn't get lost after logging in. this does however pose a serious issue and explains a lot of bugreports concerning unsaved data.

never had such an issue before, but somehow the session length seems very short on this application. been looking for a setting but haven't found any in the config file (initial stages of the project were made together with an ex-coworker and hosting isn't managed by me)

Edit 2: Well, now I just feel like an idiot. Ignored the default Startup.Auth.cs file

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) //<<DUH OBVIOUSLY
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

should've been the first place I looked when I noticed the problem occurred after a set time.

my bad

Comment: Where is the button? How *do* you submit the form? The form is an HTML entity, it's not controlled by action attributes.

Comment: How is your route defined?

Comment: the form is submitted with the enter key on the text field. I know the action doesn't control the form, just added it for completion.

Comment: just the default route
'routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }'

Comment: Is the search form submitted using a submit button or via javascript? I don't see any reasons why leaving the page idle for a while would change the submit method.

Comment: @MartinD. form gets submitted by pressing enter in the search field

Comment: @Doomchild I had the same problem with the SecurityStampValidator, I ended up writing custom SecurityStampValidator which only rejects when stamp changes and does not have a session timeout.

Answer (score 2):

With just the default route, your code won't work.  If you don't call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` in your route config, `[HttpPost]` will do nothing.  The default route configuration uses the action name to determine the HTTP verb in use.  Change your action name to `PostSearch` and it will use POST.  Similarly, `GetSearch` will make it respond to GET requests.

Comment: yeah upped... something like this annoyed the crap out of me when i was working it angular. they should make it more clear.... or i don't know where the is specified.

Comment: This is the Dark Side of convention-based routing.